# Django Multiple Databases CreateSuperUser - gives django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am Building a Django application using python 3.7.6 and Django 3.0.5. This solution has multiple applications each application will have its own standalone database configured.

I was able to successfully complete migrations. However I am Unable to CreateSuperUser. It is failing with following error - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.

My Settings file has following DB configurations -

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['ISMABlogs.Db_Router.Db_Router']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'Blogs': 'blog',
                        'ISMATutorials':'tutorial'}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    },
    'blog': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'isma_blogs',
        'USER' : 'abc',
        'PASSWORD': 'something',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':3306
    },
    'tutorial': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'isma_tutorials',
        'USER' : 'xyz',
        'PASSWORD': 'something',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':3306
    }
}

DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS='blog'
```

And My Router file has following configuration -

```
class Db_Router(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    user application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read ISMATutorials models go to ISMATutorials.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'Blogs':
            return 'blog'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'ISMATutorials':
            return 'tutorial'
        return 'blog'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write user models go to users_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'Blogs':
            return 'blog'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'ISMATutorials':
            return 'tutorial'
        return 'blog'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the user app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'Blogs' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'Blogs':
           return True
        elif obj1._meta.app_label == 'ISMATutorials' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'ISMATutorials':
           return True
        return obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'users_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'Blogs':
            return db == 'blog'
        elif app_label == 'ISMATutorials':
            return db == 'tutorial'
        return 'blog'
```

The command used for creating Admin user is -

```
py manage.py createsuperuser --database=blog
```

It is generating following stacktrace -

```
Username (leave blank to use 'india'): admin
Email address: sk_agarwals@hotmail.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 158, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 141, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 79, in execute
    raise utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")
```

Comment: I have specified DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS='blog' and also ensured my router returns a default database='blog'. So there should be a default database most of the times. However will need to debug further using full traceback, will revert back soon with more details.

Comment: I was not specifying database details correctly on the command line which was generating the earlier error of improperly configured database. I have made the corrections and also added stack trace of new error.

Comment: The `last_login` field has allowed nulls since Django 1.8, so I'm don't know how you've ended up with a not null constraint on that column. If that's the only thing that's wrong with your database schema, you can drop the not null constraint, but if there are other differences between your schema and your migrations it will be trickier to fix.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I will drop constraint on 'last_login'. Other Question, where to find out more details about default Django Schema that is created during Migrations.

Comment: Have a look at the list of [migrate commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#the-commands). `showmigrations` shows the migrations that have been applied against your database (if you used `--fake` then it might not be the migrations that were really applied). `sqlmigrate` shows the SQL for a particular migration.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, This information helps.